# ibatis exception - Database session disruption

Tags: exception, ibatis, mybatis

Im using ibatis to persist my data into database. I have an application which frequently updates the database with the values from the application for every few secs. After 5 hours of running ibatis throws this exception :

Database session disruption - org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException and later i see

#### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'updates_table' doesn't exist.

for 5 hours it was populating the same table and suddenly it throws this exception. I don't know what could be the reason. Can anyone please help me out abt this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table is not listed anymore - then look for drop statements in other parts of your code, for example periodic tasks or something.

Another possible reason might be transaction on DDL statement, which was rolled back.

Comment: Thank you. I see that its my build which is causing the database to drop the tables and recreate.